# Open hyperlinks from browser with a specific viewer

Tags: html, css, scripting

I have an html file that I can open with chrome, this html file contain some href links that allow me to open files from the html interface, my issue is that when I click on the hyperlink on the opened html file, the requested file, opened in the current browser (chrome), & what I need is that to open the link in a specific viewer or app (Editor/adobereader ..etc), so how can I achieve this using css/html please ?

```
<td><a href="link_to_the_file.txt">1884810</a></td>
```

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't imagine this is possible with just vanilla HTML and CSS. The file is opening in the browser because the browser is considering that file to be hosted by your website and not local on the machine. Typically, you'd need to download the file first before it could be opened in a text editor locally on your machine so the president isn't there. That's not to say it's absolutely impossible, just not with HTML and CSS alone.

Comment: If there is a web hosted text editor (maybe Google Docs or a similar, notepad equivalent) that could be opened within a browser, it may be possible to have it opened inside of those, but that would probably be up to the capability of those editors and my guess is that's not exactly what you're looking for.